# Primary key auto increment

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

Problems: Previously i called the function below.

```
ArchiveDeletedPatient.ID = 18
_archiveDB2.patient.Add(ArchiveDeletedPatient);
_archiveDB2.SaveChanges();
```

Afterward I deleted all records from patient database(delete from patient), now in my database it is empty. I called the above function again, however this time it auto increment ID to 19 and inserted into the database. I spamed the above functions and it kept incrementing. How to remove such function?? I don't need the auto increment.

Some might say it is because of database setting. I tried manually insert using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 17 "INSERT INTO PATIENT TABLE VALUES(18, ...). It allowed me to insert and when there is such ID in the table. It will not auto increment and will just prompt me a error. How can i remove such auto incrementing feature in c# linq.

Comment: Change the table schema. Make it so that the primary key is not "seeded" or set to auto increment.

Comment: Alright i found out my mistakes. I used Identity(1,1) which means it auto increment. Solved this problem after removing identity(1,1) thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Auto increment feature is not of linq c#.
See the table properties and can you edit the pk to remove "identity" for remove autoincrement o add "identity".
If identity is activated in bbdd, the id is calculated in database and linq return this into your entity.

Answer (score 0):

The auto incrementing is not the feature of Linq. It's the feature of Database.
Here are complete instructions to remove auto increment from MS SQLServer:

- Open your Database.
- Right click on your Table and select Design.
- Select your specific column on which you want to remove auto incrementing.
- In the column properties window click on Identity specification field and make this unchecked.
- Save table design.

Here it is...

[image]

**Note:**

If you're using Entity Framework and specifying your field with `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` remove this annotation

**or**

replace it with `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]`.

Comment: That doesn't remove the AUTO_INCREMENT specification in the database.